# How would you create a JQuery / svg click-drag select outline effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, frontend

Not sure exactly what to call it, but I am looking for a way to create a dotted outline/selection box effect via javascript/svg when you click and drag over an area, and then goes away on mouseUp (that could be added if it wasn't an original part) .

A jQuery library would be nice if it exists.  I've done some looking around, and haven't found exactly what I am looking for.
I guess the theory would be get the coord from the first click, track the mouse coord moment and adjust the box accordingly.

But not writing it from scratch would be nice.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "marquee" or possibly ["marching ants"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_ants). Do you want it to be animated while drawn, or just a dotted border? Does it need to be dotted? (Note that Windows 7 just uses a semi-opaque rectangle with more-opaque stroking for its drag selection.)

Comment: The selection box size just needs to change while being selected - animation isn't important - part of a user app interface

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a demo I made just for you :)

### Demo (Static): http://jsfiddle.net/HNH2f/1/

### Demo (Animated): http://jsfiddle.net/HNH2f/2/

You can use CSS to control the visual style of the marquee. 
You can pass one or two functions to the `trackMarquee` method; both will be called with four arguments: the x1,y1,x2,y2 bounds of the marquee. The first function will be called when the marquee is released. The second function (if present) will be called each time the marquee moves (so that you can, for example, calculate what items are within that bounding box).

When you start dragging on the SVG document (or whatever element you choose to track) it will create a `<rect class="marquee" />`; during dragging it will adjust the size of the rectangle. Use CSS (as seen in the demo) to style this rectangle however you want. I'm using the [`stroke-dasharray`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeDasharrayProperty) property to make the border dotted.

For Stack Overflow posterity, here's the code (on the off chance that JSFiddle is down):

```js
(function createMarquee(global){
  var svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
      svg   = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'svg'),
      pt    = svg.createSVGPoint();

  // Usage: trackMarquee( mySVG, function(x1,y1,x2,y2){}, function(x1,y1,x2,y2){} );
  // The first function (if present) will be called when the marquee is released
  // The second function (if present) will be called as the marquee is changed
  // Use the CSS selector `rect.marquee` to select the marquee for visual styling
  global.trackMarquee = function(forElement,onRelease,onDrag){
    forElement.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){
      var point0 = getLocalCoordinatesFromMouseEvent(forElement,evt);
      var marquee = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');
      marquee.setAttribute('class','marquee');
      updateMarquee(marquee,point0,point0);
      forElement.appendChild(marquee);
      document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove',trackMouseMove,false);
      document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup',stopTrackingMove,false);
      function trackMouseMove(evt){
        var point1 = getLocalCoordinatesFromMouseEvent(forElement,evt);
        updateMarquee(marquee,point0,point1);
        if (onDrag) callWithBBox(onDrag,marquee);
      }
      function stopTrackingMove(){
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove',trackMouseMove,false);
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup',stopTrackingMove,false);
        forElement.removeChild(marquee);
        if (onRelease) callWithBBox(onRelease,marquee);
      }
    },false);
  };

  function callWithBBox(func,rect){
    var x = rect.getAttribute('x')*1,
        y = rect.getAttribute('y')*1,
        w = rect.getAttribute('width')*1,
        h = rect.getAttribute('height')*1;
    func(x,y,x+w,y+h);
  }

  function updateMarquee(rect,p0,p1){
    var xs = [p0.x,p1.x].sort(sortByNumber),
        ys = [p0.y,p1.y].sort(sortByNumber);
    rect.setAttribute('x',xs[0]);
    rect.setAttribute('y',ys[0]);
    rect.setAttribute('width', xs[1]-xs[0]);
    rect.setAttribute('height',ys[1]-ys[0]);
  }

  function getLocalCoordinatesFromMouseEvent(el,evt){
    pt.x = evt.clientX; pt.y = evt.clientY;
    return pt.matrixTransform(el.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  }

  function sortByNumber(a,b){ return a-b }
})(window);
```

Comment: I find my approach of binding the mousemove and mouseup events inside the mousedown event to be a lot easier to code and to read, but I'm not sure if it has any drawbacks. Your approach seems over-complicated, but I don't know it it's more robust than mine

Comment: @Hoffmann To be clear, we are both binding the mousemove/up inside the mousedown. You are getting some nice benefits by using jQuery: the ability to unbind the anonymous functions specified inline with just `unbind('mousemove')`. Since I'm using only DOM methods I have to create named functions (or local variables) so that I have a handle to unregister them. Or is that not what you were referring to?

Comment: @Hoffman One benefit I get by binding the mousemove/up to the `documentElement` instead of the SVG is that the user can move and/or release the mouse outside the embedded SVG and it will be tracked properly. It's still not super robust (the user can move the mouse outside the browser and release the button), but it's more robust at least.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. I had just glanced it before and it seemed you were binding all three events at the same time.

Comment: Was playing around with the demo a bit - how would you adjust the thickness of the marquee line?  I didn't find the right variable/class to adjust(?)

Comment: @jmhead You want [`stroke-width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeWidthProperty).

Answer (score 4):

You are lucky I just made this myself. I'm using jQuery SVG plugin ( http://keith-wood.name/svg.html )

```
$("#paper2").mousedown(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    var pX= (ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft) * viewBox[2]/parseInt($("#paper2").css("width"));
    var pY= (ev.pageY - this.offsetTop)  * viewBox[3]/parseInt($("#paper2").css("height"));
    var rect = svg2.rect(
        pX, //X
        pY, //Y 
        1,1, //width and height
        { //Settings, you can make the box dotted here
            fill: 'black', "fill-opacity": 0.3, stroke: 'red', strokeWidth: 3, id:rect
        }
    )

    $("#paper2").mousemove(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var rect= $('#rect');
        var pX= (ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft) * viewBox[2]/parseInt($("#paper2").css("width")) - rect.attr("x");
        var pY= (ev.pageY - this.offsetTop)  * viewBox[3]/parseInt($("#paper2").css("height")) - rect.attr("y");
        rect.attr("width", pX);
        rect.attr("height", pY);
    });

    $("#paper2").mouseup(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var div= $("#paper2");
        div.unbind('mousemove');
        div.unbind('mouseup');
    })
});
```

paper2 is a div in which I have an svg element (so the svg element and the div have the same height/width). This is how I created the svg2 element:

```
var svg2;
var root2;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#paper2").svg({
        onLoad: function() {
            svg2= $("#paper2").svg('get');
            svg2.configure({id: 'svg2'});
            var div= $("#paper2");
            root2= svg2.root();
            $("#svg2").attr("viewBox", viewBox[0]+','+viewBox[1]+','+viewBox[2]+','+viewBox[3]);    
        },
        settings: {}
    });
}
```

If you not using viewbox on the svg element you don't need this on the calculations:

```
 * viewBox[2]/parseInt($("#paper2").css("*****"));
```

viewbox[2] would be the viewbox width and viewbox[3] would be the viewbox height.

Comment: You might be interested in the `getLocalCoordinatesFromMouseEvent` function from my answer, as this handles viewBox scaling as well was arbitrary nested transformations to whatever element you may need a mouse point for. Not necessary for the common case of tracking a marquee only on the root `<svg>`, but nicely generic and thus handles all cases, perhaps a marquee inside a translated and zoomable sub-drawing area.

Comment: You know Phrogz I was looking for a function that did that, how would I go about using that from inside a jQuery callback? I try to avoid using .get() and directely manipulating DOM elements when I use jQuery

Comment: That method needs access to a temporary `SVGPoint`; while I happen to create just one that I close over, you can also do something like: `jQuery.fn.svgCoordsFromEvent = function cursorLoc(evt){ var pt = this[0].ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint(); pt.x=evt.clientX; pt.y=evt.clientY; return pt.matrixTransform(this[0].getScreenCTM().inverse()); };`

Comment: Thanks Phrogz, that is really useful, it even works after I use a CSS transform on the whole document (which was a problem I was having). You should really talk to the author of the jQuery SVG plugin and ask him to add that little function.