# How do I select all SVG elements within a rectangle with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have written a generic javascript library that creates a various types of SVG graphs (barcharts, plots, piecharts and so forth). I also have code for a marquee selection from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673591/how-would-you-create-a-jquery-svg-click-drag-select-outline-effect) which works nicely.

So now I have x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates within my SVG and am looking for an easy way to select all SVG elements that have at least 1 pixel within that selection.

For a plot with just dots this is easily doable, but I am looking for a simple generic solution that will work for rectangles, ellipses and paths.

Comment: Post code for better understanding of the question/problem.

Comment: I have updated the question to be more specific on the parameters I have. I have the topLeft and bottomRight coordinates within my SVG and I am looking for all elements within (or partially within) these boundaries.

Comment: you could get the bounding box of each shape (getBBox) and see whether it's inside your selection, that's not foolproof though.

Comment: I can't test it now, but i can give you an opinion. You have X1, X2, Y1 and Y2 already. Now using position().top and position().left properties of $('svg path') elements you can find their X'1 and Y'1. Add width and height now you have X'2 and Y'2 too. Last thing is comparing Xs, Ys with X's and Y's. I hope this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really only a partial answer, as I can show you how to accomplish your goal in simple situations, but not in all the scenarios you proposed.

A simplistic solution would be to use `svgSvgElement.getIntersectionList`. The code below demonstrates this. It shows how to determine which of three colored triangles are "hit" by a selection rectangle. Note, however, that it determines not which *elements* overlap the selection rectangle but which *element bounding boxes* overlap the selection rectangle. Thus, the blue triangle below is considered to overlap as expected and the red triangle is considered to not overlap as expected, but the green triangle *is* considered to overlap not because the triangle itself does but because the dotted green rectangle around it does. To actually determine which shape itself overlaps the rectangle is more complicated and has been the source of much hair-pulling since the dawn of time.

```js
const qs = (selctr) => document.querySelector(selctr);

const svg   = qs('svg'   );
const green = qs('#green');
const blue  = qs('#blue' );
const red   = qs('#red'  );

const r = svg.createSVGRect();
r.x = 10;
r.y = 10;
r.width = 100;
r.height = 40;
const nodeList = svg.getIntersectionList(r, null);
const arr = Array.from(nodeList);
console.log('The following triangles "overlap" the black rectangle:');
console.log('green:', arr.indexOf(green) >= 0, '(?!)');
console.log('blue: ', arr.indexOf(blue ) >= 0);
console.log('red:  ', arr.indexOf(red  ) >= 0);
```

```html
<svg>
  <g fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="2" opacity="0.5">
    <rect x="25" y="10" width="100" height="40" stroke="black"/>
    <rect x="10" y="40" width="20" height="40" stroke="green" transform="translate(0)"/>
    <rect x="10" y="40" width="20" height="40" stroke="blue"  transform="translate(50)"/>
    <rect x="10" y="40" width="20" height="40" stroke="red"   transform="translate(120)"/>
  </g>
  <g opacity="0.5">
    <path id="green" fill="green" d="M10,40 L30,60 20,80" transform="translate(0)"/>
    <path id="blue"  fill="blue"  d="M10,40 L30,60 20,80" transform="translate(50)"/>
    <path id="red"   fill="red"   d="M10,40 L30,60 20,80" transform="translate(120)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

It has been [suggested that you could use `document.elementFromPoint`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30903000/5218951) as a sort of work-around for this. For example, you could test whether, say, any of the four corner points or the center point of your selection rectangle fall inside your shape. Note, however, that even this approach would miss the following:

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="2" opacity="0.5"/>
  <path fill="red" opacity="0.5" d="M45,30 L80,0 90,70"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome, even if not perfect, these are the functions I was looking for!

Comment: **DO NOT USE the `svg.getIntersectionList` function!** I have changed the `SVGRect (r)` to `r.x = 25` and now I have absolutly different results in IE10 and in new Opera. In Opera it is very wrong: for triangles and for all shapes and paths they take a rect. In IE is correct: triangles are triangles, paths – paths and only rects – rects. See my **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzZbKp)** for demo. See **[bugs report list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32440892/9801830#comment52754038_32440892)** for Chrome, WebKit and FF(completely missing support).

Comment: Why the alarm, @Bharata? The answer already states it takes the bounding box instead of the actual shape. And the answer (and last edition) is older than your comment (2017 vs 2019). And the compatibility list can be seen in https://caniuse.com/?search=getIntersectionList .